# Pandas: merging on columns with mixed data types

Tags: pandas, merge, missing-data, complex-data-types

I have primary and secondary data frames.  I want to replace the values in the primary data frame with values in the secondary data frame when the ID variable combinations are the same.  One of the ID variables has mixed datatypes in the primary data frame. I was able to solve the problem, but my solution seems overly complicated and I'm hoping someone out here may be able to help me find a more elegant approach.

Note that rows with ID2 = 'Missing' or with 'indicator' = 1 will never need to be replaced.

```
primary_df = pd.DataFrame(data=
        {'ID1': ['XXX111','XXX111','XXX111','XXX111','YYY222','YYY222','ZZZ333','ZZZ333','ZZZ333'],
         'ID2': ['0-100', -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, '0-10', -1.0,'300-400', 'Missing', '-4.0'],
         'value' : [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
         'indicator': [1,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan]})

secondary_df = pd.DataFrame(data=
        {'ID1': list(['XXX111','ZZZ333']),
         'ID2': list([-3,-4]),
         'value': list([0.04, 0.09])})

desired_df = pd.DataFrame(data=
        {'ID1': ['XXX111','XXX111','XXX111','XXX111','YYY222','YYY222','ZZZ333','ZZZ333','ZZZ333'],
         'ID2': ['0-100', -1, -2, -3, '0-10', -1,'300-400', 'Missing', -4],
         'value' : [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.04, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.09],
         'indicator': [1,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan]})

In [6]: primary_df
Out[6]: 
      ID1      ID2  value  indicator
0  XXX111    0-100    0.1        1.0
1  XXX111       -1    0.2        NaN
2  XXX111       -2    0.3        NaN
3  XXX111       -3    0.4        NaN
4  YYY222     0-10    0.5        1.0
5  YYY222       -1    0.6        NaN
6  ZZZ333  300-400    0.7        1.0
7  ZZZ333  Missing    0.8        NaN
8  ZZZ333     -4.0    0.9        NaN

In [7]:secondary_df
Out[7]: 
      ID1  ID2  value
0  XXX111   -3   0.04
1  ZZZ333   -4   0.09

desired_df
Out[8]: 
      ID1      ID2  value  indicator
0  XXX111    0-100   0.10        1.0
1  XXX111       -1   0.20        NaN
2  XXX111       -2   0.30        NaN
3  XXX111       -3   0.04        NaN
4  YYY222     0-10   0.50        1.0
5  YYY222       -1   0.60        NaN
6  ZZZ333  300-400   0.70        1.0
7  ZZZ333  Missing   0.80        NaN
8  ZZZ333       -4   0.09        NaN
```

Here's my very unPandorable solution:

```
pdfIndctr  = primary_df.copy()[primary_df.indicator==1] # pick up rows with indicator = 1, will never need to be replaced
pdfMissing = primary_df.copy()[primary_df['ID2']=='Missing'] # pick up rows with ID2 = 'Missing', will never need to be replaced
pdfRest    = primary_df.copy()[(primary_df['ID2'] != 'Missing') & (primary_df.indicator.isnull())] # pick up the rest of the rows
pdfRest['ID2'] = pdfRest.ID2.apply(lambda x: int(float(x))) # change the data type on ID2 for merging with secondary_df

pdfRest_fixed = pd.merge(pdfRest, secondary_df, on=['ID1','ID2'], how='inner', suffixes=['drop','']) # merge to fix the rows to be replaced
pdfRest_same  = pd.merge(pdfRest, secondary_df, on=['ID1','ID2'], how='left',  suffixes=['','drop'], indicator=True) # merge again to identify rows not to be replaced
pdfRest_same  = pdfRest_same.copy()[pdfRest_same._merge=='left_only'] # drop the rows in the second merge that were also found in the secondary_df

desired_df = pdfIndctr.append(pdfMissing, sort=True).append(pdfRest_fixed, sort=True).append(pdfRest_same, sort=True) # put everything back together
desired_df.drop(columns = ['_merge','valuedrop'], inplace=True) # drop unnecessary rows
```

Comment: Could you add your solution to the question? It's hard to determine whether a solution is more elegant when there isn't anything to compare it to. Also, `desired_df` seems to be missing a ninth value for `indicator`.

Comment: I have updated as requested, would love some help.  Thanks.